# woocommerce add dynamic price while add to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My task is :

I have test, test1, test2, test3 ==> 4 products

The test product price is $0.

While add to cart the price will be added to that particular 'test' product is $500

How to achieve this.

I use the following hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
```

But it only shows the total as 500. I need to show this price as product price in my entire cart. How to do this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: If someone still looking for an answer, i have an article for the exact purpose http://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [nice guide](http://www.xatik.com/2013/02/06/add-custom-form-woocommerce-product/) on how to add a form to a product and then change the price.

If you look for my function 'calculate_cost' and find every where it is used, you should be able to figure out how to modify the price such that 'test' is $500.

For example you could do something like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', array(&$this, 'add_cart_item'), 10, 1);
function add_cart_item($cart_item) {
    // TODO: Logic to determine when this is the 'test' product
    $cart_item['data']->set_price('500');
}
```

Comment: your nice guide is no more. :|