# woocommerce: Display products with different price according to city selection

Tags: php, location, woocommerce

I would like to add a popup when you click and go to the shop page, where the users selects the city. 
Once the city is selected, I would like to display the products with the price specific for that city that the user chose.
Each city has different prices.

Comment: Without something like that being custom coded for you, it's doubtful, but the closest I can suggest is to have each city as a category and duplicate each product for each city and set the prices that way.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to specify the exact price for every product in every city or is it possible to write simple rules that you can apply to the original price based on city(for example 10% lower rounded to closest even number)?

If you want to specify the price for every product in every city is to make meta-fields for all the cities on all the products. [The guide that Dez linked to was nice so I'll reuse that here](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/).

First set a cookie for the user that specifies the city. There are many ways to get the city value and I don't know what way you would prefer.

```
setcookie("city", $city, time() + 315360000);
```

Then use this filter to override the price that is displayed to the user:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'my_custom_price', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_custom_price', 99, 2);

function my_custom_price( $orginal_price, $product )
{
    //Get the cooke value
    $city = $_COOKIE["city"];

    //your logic for calculating the new price based on city here
    switch ($city) {
        case 'new_york':

            $new_price = round($orginal_price * 0.95); //Calculate the price (here 5% discount)
            break;

        default:
            $new_price = $orginal_price
            break;
    }

     //OR just: 
     $new_price = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'wc_price_'.$city, true ); //Retrieve the price from meta value 

     //If no matching price is found, return original price
     if( ! empty( $new_price ) ) {
         return $orginal_price;
     } 

    //Return the new price (this is the price that will be used everywhere in the store)
    return $new_price;
}
```

But beware of cache when using this solution. That might cause some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to code for this specific example so I'll bullet point what you could do.

## Option 1

1. When a user selects a city set a cookie with that city name or city_id
2. Create custom fields for products that match the city name or city_id ([Here's a guide](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/))
3. Hide the price from the user if they don't have a city set in their cookie
4. Customize the `templates/single-product/price.php` template to display the price that is mapped to their city
5. When they add the product to the cart override the price of the product ([Here's a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961102/woocommerce-add-dynamic-price-while-add-to-cart))

## Option 2

1. Use [WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)
2. Require a person to register before adding a product to the cart and have city as a register field
3. Based on what they answer for City place them in a role defined for Dynamic Pricing

**Caveat**: I'm not sure the Dynamic Pricing option is a good one for what you want because I think it displays a discount in the cart based off the user role instead of just adjusting the price of the item.

Comment: NO! Do not edit the template files when it's not necessary. This will also only work on the product page and not in the cart, checkout, product lists and widgets etc.
There are filters to override the prices everywhere, and it's simple and easy! Se my answer.

Comment: That's why I had them override the price when it was added to cart. Yes, there might be other templates to edit to make sure the price is shown for what you need it to be, but it's a valid solution.

Comment: Maybe it solves the problem, but It's far from an optimal solution and far from what is considered best practice. You should only override the templates when it's needed as a last resort. By overriding templates you make it much harder to maintain the site as there is much higher risk that something break when you update WooCommerce.
It's also a lot more work to exit several templates when you can do it clean and simple with a filter and just a few lines of code.

Comment: Possibly so, but your solution proposed makes assumptions regarding the ability to discount the price on a straight percentage basis. My feeling is that it could be a travel/tour type site and the prices they charge would be negotiated per city but can still charge for a "tour of city" product.

Comment: Because I don't know exactly what he wants I have to make assumptions. However, the function logic can be rewritten in whatever way you want and it just have the return the private you want to use on the site based on any parameters you can collect, in this case a cookie and a product object. Off course the logic can be much better depending on what is needed in this case but that is another question. You have to add the same logic in your solution, but in a lot worse way, so I really don't get your point here.

Comment: It should of course be price, not private. I don't know why I can't edit the comments on my phone anymore.